# How to unbold short table of contents headings? shortoc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, shorttoc

I am using shortoc package to create a brief contents page for my book.

I used the command:

```
\shorttoc{\sffamily BRIEF CONTENTS}{1}
```

to create it so only the sections are displayed without the subsections.

Now I need to unbold the section headings. Is there a way to do it with the shortoc package?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on etoolbox package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\shorttoc}{\@startshorttoc {toc}}{{\let\bfseries\normalfont\@startshorttoc {toc}}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\shorttoc{\sffamily BRIEF CONTENTS}{1} 
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo bar}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfect! Much thanks